# how to make sure at least one field is not empty?(its ok if only one is not empty)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I'm writing a registration endpoint for an api i'm working on and i'm using nestjs and class-validator to validate the input data.
The user can register using either their phone number or email address or both. So to validate the input, I should make sure that at least one of them is provided. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it without making a mess.

This is my dto:

```
export class register {
  @ApiModelProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  firstName: string

  @ApiModelProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  lastName: string

  @ApiModelProperty()
  @ValidateIf(o => o.email == undefined)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @isIRMobile()
  phone: string

  @ApiModelProperty()
  @ValidateIf(o => o.phone == undefined)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string

  @ApiModelProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string
}
```

As you can see, i've used conditional validation which works for the cases that only one of phone number or email address is provided. But the problem is that when both are provided, one of them won't be validated and an invalid value will be allowed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think you just need to add

```
@ValidateIf(o => o.email == undefined || o.phone)
phone: string
```

and

```
@ValidateIf(o => o.phone == undefined || o.email)
email: string
```

**EDITED**

A small addition

I'd suggest validating like this:

```
@ValidateIf(o => !o.email || o.phone)
phone: string

@ValidateIf(o => !o.phone || o.email)
email: string
```

to properly handle *null*, *0* and *""* (empty string)

otherwise, this will be correct as well (it shouldn't be):

```
const data = new register();
data.phone = '';
data.email = '';
```

Comment: You can see this feat request too: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/1581

Answer (score 1):

**This is how you can validate at least one field, It will validate only if at least one filed is correct.**

```
import {  IsNotEmpty, IsNumber, ValidateIf, Length } from 'class-validator';

    export class ProposalBody {
      @ValidateIf((req) => !req.proposalNo || req.mobileNumber)
      @IsNotEmpty()
      @IsNumber()
      @Length(10, 10, { message: "Invalid Mobile Number. It should be a 10-digit number." })
      mobileNumber: number;
    
      @ValidateIf((req) => !req.mobileNumber || req.proposalNo)
      @IsNotEmpty()
      @IsNumber()
      proposalNo: number;
    }
```